# Sumar con checkboxes en html

Tags: javascript, html

estoy intentando hacer algo asi:

```html
<p><input type="checkbox">+10</p>
<p><input type="checkbox">+50</p>
<button>boton</button>

<p>El resultado es: 0</p>
```

Como puedo hacer que al darle al boton cambie ese 0 en base a los checkboxes que haya marcado?
gracias

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usted puede lograr esto creando una función que se ejecute al darle click al botón. Debe colocar a las etiquetas un Id para verificar si están seleccionadas o no. También debe agregar un Id a la etiqueta donde usted va a presentar el resultado.

```js
// funcion sumar 
function sumar(a=0, b=0) {
  // presentar el resultado de la suma
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML= a + b;
}

// evento click
document.getElementById("sumar").onclick= function () {
  let primero = 0;
  let segundo = 0;
  // verificar si los checkbox están seleccionados
  if (document.getElementById("primero").checked) {
    primero = 10;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("segundo").checked) {     
    segundo = 50;
  }
  // llamar a la funcion sumar
  sumar(primero, segundo);
};
```

```html
<p><input id="primero" type="checkbox">+10</p>
<p><input id="segundo" type="checkbox">+50</p>
<button id="sumar">boton</button>

<p>El resultado es: <label id="resultado">0</label></p>
```

Comment: Que genial! muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)